# Adding multiple identities to ClaimsPrincipal in MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, owin, claims-based-identity

In my MVC4 application there are two ways of logging in; as a customer, or as a back office administrator.

At the moment, if you log in as either of these, the ClaimsPrincipal is replaced with a brand new one containing the single identity of the new login. It's currently impossible to be logged into both a customer account and an administrator account at the same time, which is a requirement we now have.

I felt it made sense to just add a new identity to the already existing ClaimsPrincipal, using the AddIdentity method described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsprincipal.addidentity(v=vs.110).aspx

However this wasn't adding the second identity. I then found this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mrochon/2017/06/23/claims-augmentation-post-token/

This part in particular interests me:

> Theoretically, that should be possible by adding a new ClaimsIdentity
>   to the ClaimsPrincipal. However, OWIN in ASP.NET 4 will not serialize
>   the new identity. An alternative method is to modify the existing
>   ClaimsIdentity as follows

So if's not possible in ASP.NET 4, why not? Where is this mentioned in Microsoft documentation? 
If we migrate to .NET Core, can we expect this to work? 
Are there any workarounds for this in ASP.NET 4?

Comment: Did you manage to make this work somehow?

Comment: Unfortunately I never did. As I was immediately downvoted for even asking this question, I was led to believe this was bad practice. I asked this question a year ago and can't remember what I did. I think I used a single custom claims principal which had claims for the different identities.